# Is it possible to get all MySQL table associations based on one Primary Key?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

Trying to create a query to programatically retrieve all known table associations of a given, dynamic, table.

Closest I've come up with is using a Left Join query like, but the table i would be joining must be known beforehand.

Comment: You will possibly want to look at schema tables -> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was attempting to programatically find tables with a given criteria and find all associated tables with each one, so that I could preemptively avoid orphaned data.

I solved this by manually finding the initial tables and hard-coding the queries into my program.

e.g.

```
for (let i = 0; i < knownTables.length; i++) {
    query(`DELETE * FROM ${knownTables[i]} WHERE columnExample IS NOT NULL;`)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create array of tables (`SHOW TABLES`) - and try to run your query in each table.